# Find the number of PINs that contain at least one sequence of three/two consecutive digits

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

a PIN is a string of four decimal digits, e.g. 2357, 0944 etc.

I am wondering how to find the number of PINs that contain a**t least one sequence of three consecutive digits** $n; n+1; n+2$ (e.g. 2340, 5678 etc).

And the number of PINs that contain **at least one sequence of two
consecutive digits** $n; n+1$ (e.g. 7340, 5671 etc).

It seems that I need to use inclusion and exclusion principle to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that one way to solve this problem is with the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

For the "at least 3 consecutive digits" case, note that there are 8 possible sets of 3 consecutive digits. These digits can be at the right of the pin (like X234) or at the left (234X), where X can be any digit. This gives $8 \cdot 2 \cdot 10 = 160$ pins. However, we have now counted pins with 4 consecutive digits 2 times: for example, 1234 is counted as 123X and X234. Thus we subtract the number of these pins which is 7 to get $153$ pins with at least 3 consecutive digits.

You can extend this method to the second part too. Add all pins with 2 known consecutive digits, subtract some with 3 known consecutive digits, add some with 4 consecutive digits, where "some" is chosen such that each of those categories is counted exactly once.

Comment: Thanks so much. The second part seems a bit complicated. By the same method, I get $9*3*10*10=2700$ pins. Then I am not sure what I have over-counted.

Comment: To start off, how many times have you counted the pin 1235? How many times have you counted the pin 123X for any X?

Comment: For $1235$, this has been counted as $12XX$ and $X23X$.

Comment: OK. What about a general pin with 3 consecutive digits?

Comment: Is that $8*2$? because I can have $123X,234X,... X123,X234,...$. For each one, I over-counted once.

Comment: Yes. But now you have "under-counted" the number of pins with 4 consecutive digits. Add those back in and you will have the answer.

Comment: So the answer is $2700-16+7$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is.